# Difference between .h files and .inc files in c

Tags: c, include, header-files

I have been looking at various open source projects, and they have a bunch of files written in C that have `.inc` as a file extension. As far as I can tell, they are used like header files.

I thought the standard convention was to use `.h` files for header files and `.c` for source files. So, is there a standard convention on when a header file should be an `.inc` file rather than being a `.h` file, or are these decided only at a per project basis? (Or am I just looking at weird projects that use `.inc`?)

Comment: Conventions are just that - conventions.  There's no rule that says header files *must* use a `.h` extension, or that implementation files *must* use a `.c` extension (although most compilers and IDEs will expect you to follow that convention).  Having said that, using `.inc` for headers is unusual in my experience.

Comment: An `.inc` file is not a header file. it could be used to include a large defined array just to keep it out of the way of the source file editing.

Comment: @JohnBode of course it's just a convention. ;) But its still useful to actually _know_ what the conventions are.

Comment: @WeatherVane ah, cool, thank you.

Comment: All of the standard library header files, and all those of any third-party library I have ever come across, use the `.h` naming convention.  It is a strong enough convention to be considered a *de facto* rule.  I might consider a different convention for files that do not contain declarations but rather executable code or internal data, yet that are intended to be `#include`d by other files.  In my experience, however, such things are rare.

Comment: ...and such an `.inc` file might have been *generated* rather than typed. In that case the generating program will only want to write the minimum overhead that makes it usable as source code. Then the programmer won't have to keep copy/pasting with every tweak of the data.

Comment: Just to expand on @WeatherVane's answer, an `.inc` file is usually an "outsourced" part of a specific source file. It (usually) shouldn't be included by other files (as it will create name collisions for functions or variables it declares).

Comment: The only place I have seen `.inc` file suffix used is with PHP.  Are you sure the file contains C?

Comment: @cdarke I am indeed sure. Unless PHP now uses pragma and ifndef and whatnot. Here is an example file: https://github.com/racket/racket/blob/master/racket/src/racket/cmdline.inc

Comment: Ah, certainly C.  I can guess at the logic at not calling them `.h` files.  The standard header files (e.g. stdio.h) are *idempotent*.  That is, if you include too many, or they are included more than once, they should have no effect on the program.  They are only supposed to contain things like macros, prototypes, structs/unions, maybe `extern`, but nothing that should affect the size of the final code.  The file you show contains functions, which by convention should not be in a header file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard convention is to use `.h` for header files that contain only macro definitions and other declarations and `.c` for C source files that contain code and data definitions.

In some projects, code fragments are stored in separate files and included in C source files with some macro tricks to expand specifically in different files or circumstances. Sometimes, these files are even included multiple times in the same source file. To underscore the **special** semantics attached to such files, giving them a different extension may be a useful hint.  These files may also have been generated as part of the build process: naming them specifically may prevent confusion with actual source files.

Look at the files you came across in these projects and verify if this explanation holds.

Answer (score 6):

`.inc` files are often associated with templated classes and functions.

Standard classes and functions are declared with a `.h` file and then defined with a `.cpp` file. However, a template is neither a class nor a function but a pattern that is used to generate a family of classes or functions. In order for the compiler to generate the code for the template, it needs to see both the declaration and definition and therefore they both must be included in the `.h` file.

To keep the declaration and definition separate, the definition is placed in its own file and included at the end of the `.h` file. This file will have one of many possible file extensions `.inc`, `.imp`, `.impl`, `.tpp`, etc.

Declaration example:

```
// Foo.h
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

template<typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
    void DoSomething(T x);
private:
    T x;
};

#include "Foo.inc"
#endif // FOO_H
```

Definition example:

```
// Foo.inc
#include "Foo.h"

template<typename T>
Foo<T>::Foo() {
    // ...
}

template<typename T>
void Foo<T>::DoSomething(T x) {
    // ...
}
```